# Caffemodel and prototxt

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, caffe

```
ageNet=dnn.readNet("age_net.caffemodel","age_deploy.prototxt")
maskNet = load_model("ask_detector.model")
```

**I am very much curious about the purpose of caffemodel and protext.**

I have surfed many materials
but I couldn't grasp it.

Kindly give me an analogy to understand the above lines and their working.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/net_layer_blob.html) (last section, "Model format")? I would avoid using Caffe at all in 2021 :)

Answer (score 1):

**age_deploy.prototxt** contains the details of the model architecture for the age detection model

**caffemodel** has the pre-trained model weights for age detection